# Error while restoring the page in Hybris 1811 smart edit

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, backoffice

I am trying to restore a content page (which is a primary page) but when I am selecting the radio button "Restore this page and move the existing page to trash" it shows error "The value provided is already in use."

But as per below SAP documentation if I have same page name and page label, it supposed to restore this page and move the existing page to trash but it is throwing an error. Did anyone faced similar issues. Your help would be much appreciated. Thank you.

https://help.sap.com/viewer/86dd1373053a4c2da8f9885cc9fbe55d/1811/en-US/9c46244de9e242bdaba0b3da6621dc85.html

[image]

Comment: Do you have another page that is named "chola"?

Answer (score 0):

We can restore the page only when Page ID and Page Label is same but Page name should be unique. but the document says we can restore the page when Page name and Page Label is same.